# UIView Bounds Are Not Changing Even After viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard

I have a UIView that draws a path inside it. As such I need to expand the bounds so the paths line is not cut off.

This view has been added to a ViewController in a Storyboard. In that ViewController's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method I explicitly override the bounds of the UIView.

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        pathView.bounds = CGRect(x:-20,
                        y:-20,
                        width: 1000,
                        height: 1000)
    }
```

I set the width and height to 1000 to make sure I could see the effect. However the bounds are unchanged:

[image]

The red is the bounds and the green line is the line drawn within those bounds.

When I view this object in the view debugger it is clear the bounds have been overridden somewhere:

[image]

Do you know why my bounds are being overridden even after the viewDidLayoutSubviews call and how I can actually set the bounds for this view?

**Note** It is interesting that the position of the bounds, -20,-20, is working. But the width and height are reset(kept?) at the 200 x 200 width and height constraints it was given in the storyboard. Somehow the frame constraints are also setting the bounds too?

Comment: When you're using auto-layout you are not supposed to change bounds directly... You can either change the constraints themselves or not use auto-layout for this view and handle the layout manually.

Comment: Originally I was not using AutoLayout. But the position I would get for the x and y would change and I couldn't get consistent return values. I thought putting the view directly into the storyboard and then just tweaking the bounds would be the easier way to go

Comment: Also, x & y values other than zero for bounds, only make sense if you intend to show a portion of your view and doesn't describe it's position in the superview (that is the purpose of the frame's origin)

Comment: Have you tried **viewWillLayoutSubviews()**? I'd think that the views have already been rendered in the override you are using.

Comment: @dfd I have tried that and it makes no difference sadly

Comment: So you are using autlayout currently **and** trying to change the bounds manually?